# GTM Virtual Pageview not firing

Tags: google-tag-manager

I've set a DataLayer into a landing page that looks something like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmQb9.png).

I've set a trigger on GTM which fires upon custom event = "VirtualPageview" and attached it to a Universal Analytics tag which will return to me it's variables. On debug mode, it displays success upon the trigger, but the tag itself is not firing. See [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmgsd.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fhtj.png).

Comment: Are there any other rules in the trigger?
Can you show a more complete picture of the configuration?

Comment: It's pretty much that, that's the only rule to firing the tag... I'm currently talking to the support to figure it out

Comment: Where you took the screenshot of your second image (https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fhtj.png), scroll down in GTM debug to Firing Triggers and take a screenshot of that to show me. So we can see what doesn't match.